# How to Disable "Upload" in IMCE to only keep "File browser"?

Tags: files

I'm working on a website (Drupal 6) where filefield and IMCE are set to upload media into nodes.

The customer don't want the users to upload files in the default directory but in specific places, for this reason he asks me to remove the "upload" possibility and only keep the "file browser".

How can I say to the widget to use "file browser" by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to:

> Administration » Configuration » Media » IMCE

Select your profile.
Under Directories there are checkboxes: *Browse*,*Upload*,*Thumbnails*,*Delete*,*Resize*.

Uncheck: *Upload*